# Телеграмм-бот обращения к фотографиям на компе

Tags: telegram-bot

Доброе время суток! Хочу написать телеграмм бот. Суть его: есть пронумерованные фотографии на компе (шахматная диаграмма). Хочу чтобы бот выдавал диаграмму по названию раздела(например мат в 1 ход) и дальше по номеру уже саму диаграмму. Под диаграммы нужно написать правильный ответ и если он действительно правильный то выходит уведомление(ну или любой другой индикатор, который проще реализовать) задача решена верно или не верно.
Может кто подсказать как это реализовать?!

Answer (score 0):

Павел, за Вас код никто не напишет (бесплатно, разумеется). Привели бы примеры как пытались, тогда и помощь придет. В общем случае порядок действий такой:

1. Регистрация бота в Telegram Bot Father и получение API токена.
2. Размещение фото на каком-либо хранилище или создание сервера на вашем ПК. 1-е, думаю, практичнее.
3. Написание кода на любом ЯП, который будет служить основой для бота (напр., python-telegram-bot)
4. Подключение к БД или хранение информации о диаграммах и правильных ответах в виде словаря или файла.
5. Реализация логики отправки фотографий и проверки правильности ответов в вашем коде.
6. Запуск и тестирование вашего бота.